# Left Join and condition on Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, join

[image]

I want such a query that returns all rows from Table 1 jointest1 and the row that matches join condition with Table 2 jointest2 except the duplicate rows in jointest2

Table after join should look

[image: Table After join]

the query will be like

```
SELECT * FROM jointest1 LEFT JOIN jointest2 ON jointest1.id=jointest2.j1_id WHERE jointest2.id NOT IN ( 2 )
```

but when I am adding `WHERE jointest2.id NOT IN ( 2 )` Left join is not working , it is only returning row that is `jointest1.id=jointest2.j1_id and NOT IN ( 2 )`

Thanks in advance for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `left join` is working fine.  When you have a condition on the *second* table, it needs to go in the `on` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM jointest1 LEFT JOIN
     jointest2
     ON jointest1.id = jointest2.j1_id AND
        jointest2.id NOT IN ( 2 );
```

Otherwise, the condition (even `NOT IN`) will return `NULL`, turning the `LEFT JOIN` into an `INNER JOIN`.